# how to set border color for webkit browsers?

Tags: css

Actually this code ,

-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(white), to(black));

is filling the colors for the whole control like textbox or buttons.

But the code which I got from this site is shown below works only on borders.
This fills my need in mozilla. If i want to give gradients to border in webkit what should i use? Pls help me..

-moz-border-top-colors:#7dbec5  #e9ecec #eaecec #f1f2f2 #f2f3f3 #f7f8f8 #f9f9f9 #fafafa;
-moz-border-right-colors:#7dbec5  #e9ecec #eaecec #f1f2f2 #f2f3f3 #f7f8f8 #f9f9f9 #fafafa;
-moz-border-left-colors:#7dbec5 #e9ecec #eaecec #f1f2f2 #f2f3f3 #f7f8f8 #f9f9f9 #fafafa;
-moz-border-bottom-colors:#7dbec5  #e9ecec #eaecec #f1f2f2 #f2f3f3 #f7f8f8 #f9f9f9 #fafafa;

Answer (score 3):

What I can see here  : http://help.dottoro.com/lclxpenm.php ,
it's there's no similar property for webkit browsers (you can check the list on the left).
But you can used the -webkit-box-shadow property to do the trick (http://help.dottoro.com/lceuwxiv.php#-webkit-box-shadow).

Here is an example code (works on webkit browsers) :
http://jsfiddle.net/fvXm7/

Answer (score 0):

Gradients for border images are currently not working properly in webkit. As you note, they don't stay clipped to the border box, they overflow into the padding and content boxes.